# Having issue with Segues in iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass data from table cells to a new viewController. The table in the first viewController is populated from a Azure table.

I keep getting the error message 
"use of undeclared identifier 'object'"

with this portion of code:

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *item = [self.todoService.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];  
        }
      }
```

Cheers

Comment: Because object is unidentified. What is it? You might as well call it sausages. How does the segue method have any idea what it is?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable named 'object'.  It looks like your variable is "item".

Change to:

```
   [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:item];
```

Comment: Thanks! however when i do that, i get the error "no known instance method for selector 'setDetailItem:"

Comment: Typecast the results of `[segue destinationViewController]` whatever your UIViewController subclass may be.

Comment: sorry, could you break that comment down into baby steps, not quite sure what you mean